# How to make sure that the data in this PyTrends function comes out in YYYY-MM-DD format and not YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have the following function:

```
def my_funct(Keyword, Dates, Country, Col_name):
    KEYWORDS=[Keyword] 
    KEYWORDS_CODES=[pytrend.suggestions(keyword=i)[0] for i in KEYWORDS] 
    df_CODES= pd.DataFrame(KEYWORDS_CODES)
    

    EXACT_KEYWORDS=df_CODES['mid'].to_list()
    
    DATE_INTERVAL= Dates
    COUNTRY=[Country] #Use this link for iso country code
    CATEGORY=0 # Use this link to select categories
    SEARCH_TYPE='' #default is 'web searches',others include 'images','news','youtube','froogle' (google shopping)


    Individual_EXACT_KEYWORD = list(zip(*[iter(EXACT_KEYWORDS)]*1))
    Individual_EXACT_KEYWORD = [list(x) for x in Individual_EXACT_KEYWORD]
    dicti = {}
    i = 1

    for Country in COUNTRY:
        for keyword in Individual_EXACT_KEYWORD:
            try:
                pytrend.build_payload(kw_list=keyword, 
                                      timeframe = DATE_INTERVAL, 
                                      geo = Country, 
                                      cat=CATEGORY,
                                      gprop=SEARCH_TYPE) 
                dicti[i] = pytrend.interest_over_time()
                i+=1
                time.sleep(6)
            except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
                print("Timeout occured")
        
            df_trends = pd.concat(dicti, axis=1)


            df_trends.columns = df_trends.columns.droplevel(0) #drop outside header
            df_trends = df_trends.drop('isPartial', axis = 1) #drop "isPartial"
            df_trends.reset_index(level=0,inplace=True) #reset_index
            df_trends.columns=['date', Col_name] #change column names
    
    
    return df_trends
```

Then I call the function using:

```
x1 = my_funct('Unemployment', '2004-01-04 2009-01-04', 'DK', 'Unemployment (Denmark)')
```

Then I put that into a df:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(x1)
```

Once I convert that df to excel, how do I ensure that it is in YYYY-MM-DD format without the dangling 00:00:00? Anytime I convert it comes out with hours and seconds.

I tried df1 = pd.DataFrame(x1).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') but it says that this cannot be used?

Please help
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are trying pass `dt.strftime` on the entire dataframe, but you need to pass it on the `date` column:

```
df1['date'] = df1['date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```